# *ngFor error on item select - Angular

Tags: angular, select, ngfor

I am trying to dib dropdown with "ng For". I am able to see all my entries in drop down but when I am selecting an entry it starts throwing an error. The error is "Error trying to diff '1'. Only arrays and iterable are allowed"

HTML:-

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="customerGroup">Group</label>
    <select [(ngModel)]="customerGroup" (change)="onGroupChange($event)">
        <option *ngFor="let item of customerGroup" [value]="item.groupId">{{item.groupName}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

TS:-

```
private customerGroup: any[] = [{
groupId: 1,
groupName: 'Group 1'
```

}];

```
public onGroupChange(event): void { 
const groupId = event.target.value;
```

}

[Click Here for Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYmUw.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've used array var for model variable also. Use different variable for select & it'll work fine.

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="customerGroup">Group</label>
  <select name="customerGroup" [(ngModel)]="selectedCustomerGroup" (change)="onGroupChange($event)">
  <option *ngFor="let item of customerGroup" [value]="item.groupId">{{item.groupName}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Keey everything else same.

```
  customerGroup: any[] = [{
    groupId: 1,
    groupName: 'Group 1'
  },
  {
    groupId: 2,
    groupName: 'Group 2'
  }];

  onGroupChange(event): void { 
    let groupId = event.target.value;
    //console.log(groupId);
  }
```

[**Demo Example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/lMK6yOq3G5xgri2iDnYR?p=preview)

Comment: Worth mentioning that the error is produced because the ngModel is updating the customerGroup by setting a normal string / number into it. Then angular tries to render the options and fails because it is not an array any longer